# Faster way to find and replace using a lookup table in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a series IDs in a text file using a lookup table in python. The file(s) to be converted can be of any format so flexibility is important. An example might be:

```
IDBreakfast    Oatmeal
IDBreakfast    cereal
IDLunch    sandwich
```

In the example above the IDBreakfast appears on multiple lines. The input files are also not always going to be tab separated.

The lookup table has a fixed structure, one old ID for one new ID, tab separated:

```
IDBreakfast    PetitDejeuner
IDLunch    Dejeuner
```

Right now I read the file to be converted, line by line, then loop through the lookup table doing a find and replace. This is slow. My intuition is I should be using a dictionary here, would this be faster?

```
infile = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
lookup = open(sys.argv[2],'r')
outfile = open(sys.argv[1]+".converted", 'w')

for line in infile:
    newline = line
    with open(sys.argv[2],'r') as lookup:
        for record in lookup:
            subrecord=record.rstrip()
            old = subrecord.split('\t')[0]
            new = subrecord.split('\t')[1]
            newline = newline.replace(old, new)
    outfile.write(newline)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: All you need to do is to read the lookup file into a dictionary, and then use that inside the conversion loop. That way you only read the lookup file once, not once per line of the input file.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a good way to go.

```
import sys

# Create the look up table (dictionary)
lut = {}
with open(sys.argv[2],'r') as lookup:
    for line in lookup:
        if '\t' in line:
            key, value = line.strip().split('\t')
            lut[key] = value

# Go through each line in the input file and replace where applicable
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as infile, open(sys.argv[1]+".converted", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if '\t' in line:
            key,value = line.strip().split('\t')
            if key in lut:
                outfile.write(f"{key}\t{lut[key]}\n")
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
        else:
            outfile.write(line)
```